# What to place in header to use the Facebook PHP web SDK properly?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a website with a working user signup and login system. Recently, I decided that I should add Facebook signup option. I wish to add a Facebook sign in button in the signup page and get their email, first name and last name on sign in so they don't have to insert their details.

I read though most of the Facebook developer help docs including:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile

Those links tells me how to let a user to login and how to get user data from their profile.

I understand how all those parts work but I don't know how to put them together. Can anyone please teach me how to do so? Thank you soooo much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found how to do it...

So, the first part is to set up files correctly. Here is how you do it:

1. Download the php sdk kit from fb [(here)](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/archive/5.0.0.zip)
2. Place the files in the "src" folder to your website main directory

The second part is to make the page where you want to link with fb:

1. Include the fb autoload page in your php page by doing 
   `require_once 'autoload.php';` at the top of the file
2. Authorize fb to use your app by placing

   $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
   'app_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
   'app_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
   'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
   ]);

right after the code in 1st step

This is basicly how you should start your code to link with fb user profile. The following code is what i used to get a user's name, email and profile image.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'app_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // optional

try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    } else {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
 }

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    } else {
        // getting short-lived access token
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        // setting default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }

    // redirect the user back to the same page if it has "code" GET variable
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        header('Location: ./');
    }

    // getting basic info about user
    try {
        $profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email');
        $requestPicture = $fb->get('/me/picture?redirect=false&height=300');
        $picture = $requestPicture->getGraphUser();

        $profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        session_destroy();
        // redirecting user back to app login page
        header("Location: ./");
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // printing $profile array on the screen which holds the basic info about user

    // Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} else {
    // replace your website URL same as added in the developers.facebook.com/apps e.g. if you used http instead of https and you used non-www version or www version of your website then you must add the same here
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://xxxxx', $permissions);    
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $loginUrl . '">';}
?>
```

I wish that this could help anyone who is also stuck like me, bye~